# why can't my first post request success on react native custom hooks with axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

my custom hooks :

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../context/app.context";

const usePostAxios = (url) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { setUrl, token } = useContext(AppContext);

  const postData = async (data) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Authreq"] = token;

      await axios
        .post(`${setUrl}/${url}`, data)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          setData(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err.response || err.request);
        });

      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return [isLoading, postData, data, error];
};

export { usePostAxios };
```

for posting data :

```
const [isPosting, postFun, res, err] = usePostAxios("/apidet/EmpLog");

const handleSubmit = async (val) => {
    await postFun({
      UserName: val.email,
      password: val.pass,
    });

    if (res) {
      const { Apd, Apt } = res.ResponseData;
      dispatch({ type: "APP-LOGIN", token: `${Apd}:${Apt}` });
      setIsError(false);
      navigate("Home");
      return;
    } else {
      setIsError(true);
      return;
    }
  };
```

then why my code is getting in else block and getting error but when i press submit button again the code run successfully and my login process success

so why is my code not running on first try ?

am i doing something stupid ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, wrote in this way, basically, when this this code is excecuted

```
if(res) {  
  // Something to do with result
}
```

the variable `res` has `null` as value, initially.

You should check for changes in `res` with `useEffect` instead, like:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if(res) {
    // Something to do with result
  }
}, [res])
```

Comment: That check is in an event handler, how are you going to call a hook? "The variable res is not yet with a value" yes it is, it's the result of `useState` in the custom hook and is initialized to `null`.

Comment: can u please tell me how can i make submit request then ?

because i can't understand how i make it function in group if i separate my post request in function and then observe it

Comment: Well, not exactly, since the hook has `res` as a dependency, second parameter, this should be triggered every time `res` is updated. The logic should be correct, maybe the user that posted the question have to adapt what is inside the `if` statement with custom logic.

Comment: can u please share that logic if u don't mind ?

Comment: @JaredSmith, you are right, let me change the text to be "the variable has `null` as value"

Comment: @designamitaujas, the logic should be, more or less, the same as you put before. Try to `console.log(res)` to check the value of `res` in the `useEffect` callback code, you should be able to get your res properly.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qxq2S9a.png
so if i do this shoudn't my code run on first try and it could cause the issue without even submitting the request and throw error in react 1st render ?

Comment: Well, if written in the way you shared in this last comment, yes, you will have an error even if there is no error. `setIsError` have to be wrapped by an if too, or you can do something like `setIsError(error || flase)`.

Comment: any other way i can achive this thing ? because i get it that my problem is the first time it getting null and thern im getting cached value 2nd time so any suggetion how can i call it in one function ?